# Unit test for the validity of a reactive form with FormArray

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I want to test my reactive form, this is my ts component :

```ts
policyForm = new FormGroup({

policyNumber : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
damageNumber : new FormControl('', Validators.required),
coverages :new FormArray([], this.minSelectedCheckboxes(1)),
coveragesValue:new FormArray([]),
policyConditions : new FormControl('')
 })

ngOnInit() {
this.getcoveragestype()
}

getcoveragestype(){
  this.coveragestypes = this.coverageService.getCoverages() ;
  this.addCheckboxes();
}
addCheckboxes() {
  this.coveragestypes.forEach(() => this.coverageFormArray.push(new FormControl(false)));
  this.coveragestypes.forEach(() => this.coveragesValueFormArray.push(new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/))));
 }
get coverageFormArray() {
  return this.policyForm.controls.coverages as FormArray;
 }
get coveragesValueFormArray() {
  return this.policyForm.controls.coveragesValue as FormArray;
 }
```

**I have a list of checkboxes and when one of them is checked an input form appear**

This is my spec.ts component :

```ts
it('form should be valid', () => {
fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.controls['policyNumber'].setValue('policy587?;');
fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.controls['damageNumber'].setValue('damagex');
fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.controls['coverages'].setValue('[true,false,false,false,false,false]');
fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.controls['coveragesValue'].setValue('[1254,784,1000,1025,1589,10236]');
fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.controls['policyConditions'].setValue('hi I am testing this component');


expect (fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.valid).toBeTruthy();
})
```

But it gives me this error :  `TypeError: value.forEach is not a function`

Can anyone help me to fix this ?

Comment: can you add a console.log in addCheckboxes method to check if there is a value in coveragestypes?

Answer (score 0):

I delete the '' in the setValue of the FormArray in the spec.ts component like that :

```
it('form should be valid', () => {
fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.controls['policyNumber'].setValue('policy587?;');
fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.controls['damageNumber'].setValue('damagex');
fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.controls['coverages']. 
 setValue([true,false,false,false,false,false]);
fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.controls['coveragesValue']. 
 setValue([1254,784,1000,1025,1589,10236]);
fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.controls['policyConditions'].setValue('hi I am 
 testing this component');


expect (fixture.componentInstance.policyForm.valid).toBeTruthy();
})
```

And it works